# Parallel doesnt work with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, parallel-processing

I have a list of IDs, and I need to run several stored procedures on each ID.

When I am using a standard foreach loop, it works OK, but when I have many records, it works pretty slow.

I wanted to convert the code to work with EF, but I am getting an exception:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

I am using this code, inside the `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
using (XmlEntities osContext = new XmlEntities())
{
    //The code
}
```

But it still throws the exception.

Any idea how can I use `Parallel` with EF? Do I need to create a new context for every procedure I am running? I have around 10 procedures, so I think its very bad to create 10 contexts, one for each.

Comment: I'm not a multithreaded guru, but if you're using transactions or your read/write gets locked, you may not get better performance than just doing it serially.

Comment: I doubt hammering the stressed sql server with more threads will not help performance...

Comment: The sql is not stressed at all, thats why I want to use a parallel. and it will surely run faster.

Comment: On the first loop its crashing

Comment: Why would you want to use `.ToParallel()` on EF? It won't improve performance.

Comment: @IdoLazar: Good chance you would be wrong.  For my particular application, I find that around 6 parallel tasks is ideal.  Even that is limited by lock contention that the EF team is looking at

Answer (score 46):

[The underlying database connections that the Entity Framework are using are *not* thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9099359/50776).  You *will* need to create a new context for each operation on another thread that you're going to perform.

Your concern about how to parallelize the operation is a valid one; that many contexts are going to be expensive to open and close.

Instead, you might want to invert how your thinking about parallelizing the code.  It seems you're looping over a number of items and then calling the stored procedures in serial for each item.

If you can, create a new [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (or [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), if you don't need a result) for each *procedure* and then in that `Task<TResult>`, open a single context, loop through all of the items, and then execute the stored procedure.  This way, you only have a number of contexts equal to the number of stored procedures that you are running in parallel.

Let's assume you have a `MyDbContext` with two stored procedures, `DoSomething1` and `DoSomething2`, both of which take an instance of a class, `MyItem`.

Implementing the above would look something like:

```
// You'd probably want to materialize this into an IList<T> to avoid
// warnings about multiple iterations of an IEnumerable<T>.
// You definitely *don't* want this to be an IQueryable<T>
// returned from a context.
IEnumerable<MyItem> items = ...;

// The first stored procedure is called here.
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => { 
    // Create the context.
    using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
    // Cycle through each item.
    foreach (MyItem item in items)
    {
        // Call the first stored procedure.
        // You'd of course, have to do something with item here.
        ctx.DoSomething1(item);
    }
});

// The second stored procedure is called here.
Task t2 = Task.Run(() => { 
    // Create the context.
    using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
    // Cycle through each item.
    foreach (MyItem item in items)
    {
        // Call the first stored procedure.
        // You'd of course, have to do something with item here.
        ctx.DoSomething2(item);
    }
});

// Do something when both of the tasks are done.
```

If you *can't* execute the stored procedures in parallel (each one is dependent on being run in a certain order), then you can still parallelize your operations, it's just a little more complex.

You would look at [creating custom partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx) across your items (using the static [`Create` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create.aspx) on the [`Partitioner` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.aspx)).  This will give you the means to get [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) implementations (note, this is *not* [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) so you can't `foreach` over it).

For each `IEnumerator<T>` instance you get back, you'd create a new `Task<TResult>` (if you need a result), and in the `Task<TResult>` body, you would create the context and then cycle through the items returned by the `IEnumerator<T>`, calling the stored procedures in order.

That would look like this:

```
// Get the partitioner.
OrdinalPartitioner<MyItem> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(items);

// Get the partitions.
// You'll have to set the parameter for the number of partitions here.
// See the link for creating custom partitions for more
// creation strategies.
IList<IEnumerator<MyItem>> paritions = partitioner.GetPartitions(
    Environment.ProcessorCount);

// Create a task for each partition.
Task[] tasks = partitions.Select(p => Task.Run(() => { 
        // Create the context.
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
        // Remember, the IEnumerator<T> implementation
        // might implement IDisposable.
        using (p)
        // While there are items in p.
        while (p.MoveNext())
        {
            // Get the current item.
            MyItem current = p.Current;

            // Call the stored procedures.  Process the item
            ctx.DoSomething1(current);
            ctx.DoSomething2(current);
        }
    })).
    // ToArray is needed (or something to materialize the list) to
    // avoid deferred execution.
    ToArray();
```

Comment: your last piece of code is brilliant, and you wrote it without even trying it, because of typos :) .. nice!

Answer (score 7):

EF is not thread safe, so you cannot use Parallel.

Take a look at [Entity Framework and Multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099359/entity-framework-and-multi-threading)

and this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e5cb847c-1d77-4cd0-abb7-b61890d99fae/).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use and works great. It additionally supports handling of the error exceptions and has a debug mode which makes it far easier to track things down

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<Exception> Parallel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action, int? parallelCount = null, bool debugMode = false)
{
    var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
    if (debugMode)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            try
            {
                action(item);
            }
            // Store the exception and continue with the loop.                     
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Enqueue(e);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var partitions = Partitioner.Create(items).GetPartitions(parallelCount ?? Environment.ProcessorCount).Select(partition => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (partition.MoveNext())
            {
                try
                {
                    action(partition.Current);
                }
                // Store the exception and continue with the loop.                     
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    exceptions.Enqueue(e);
                }
            }
        }));
        Task.WaitAll(partitions.ToArray());
    }
    return exceptions;
}
```

You use it like the following where as db is the original DbContext and db.CreateInstance() creates a new instance using the same connection string.

```
        var batch = db.Set<SomeListToIterate>().ToList();
        var exceptions = batch.Parallel((item) =>
        {
            using (var batchDb = db.CreateInstance())
            {
                var batchTime = batchDb.GetDBTime();
                var someData = batchDb.Set<Permission>().Where(x=>x.ID = item.ID).ToList();
                //do stuff to someData
                item.WasMigrated = true; //note that this record is attached to db not batchDb and will only be saved when db.SaveChanges() is called
                batchDb.SaveChanges();        
            }                
        });
        if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            logger.Error("ContactRecordMigration : Content: Error processing one or more records", new AggregateException(exceptions));
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions); //optionally throw an exception
        }
        db.SaveChanges(); //save the item modifications
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something I did to solve my problem.  I was trying to get an order inside my Parallel.ForEach with a unique connection to EF, this is what I tought it was but wasn't really true and I was having the same last order each time.  After removing the using and closing the connection at the end of the operation it was working just fine.

In a nutshell if you utilize a using, don't and close the connection at the end of the operation inside the Parallel.Foreach

I did replace this

```
using ApplicationDbContext Context = CubiCommon.GetContext<ApplicationDbContext>("APIConnection");
```

by this

```
ApplicationDbContext Context = CubiCommon.GetContext<ApplicationDbContext>("APIConnection");
```

and added this at the end of the operation

```
Context.Dispose();
Context = null;
```

Maybe this can solve similar issue

Comment: It's not clear how this changed the scope of the context. What does the replacement look like with surrounding code? And why `Context = null;`?

Comment: @Gert Arnold I can't explain why, I just gave a solution that solved my problem.  Sorry for nulling the Context it's a old habit from me to always nulling my instance even with a Dispose.  You may ommit it if you desire but it doesn't change a thing anyway.  I wrote the whole answer to expose what solved the EF issue for me without knowing why exactly it solved it.

Comment: Well, the way you show it here is pretty meaningless; `using` or `Dispose` doesn't make a (technical) difference.

Comment: If what you say is true then why the result is correct without using ?  Do you have any reasonable explanation for that ?  The important thing in this is the fact that a problem occurs with EF during a Parallel.ForEach with using statement and works like a charm without it.  I honestly don't know why but I just wanted to help others based on my issue.

Comment: What I say (already in the first comment) is that without any wider context it's impossible to see how this would a difference.

Comment: I agree.  If I find more detail I'll come post it!  Thanx for clarifying the unclear