# Parallel.ForEach inside a using statement hangs

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

what is wrong with this code. It hangs:

```
public static IEnumerable<Piece> allPiecesList;
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Piece> allPiecesCD = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Piece>();

using (var dc = new MyDataContext())
{
     allPiecesList = dc.PopulateAllPieces("A").ToList();
     Parallel.ForEach(allPiecesList , (piece) => allPiecesCD.TryAdd(piece.Name, piece)); 
}
```

Note: PopulateAllPieces uses Linq to SQL behind the covers. However, that is all done and we have a IEnumerable before the Parallel part starts.

MyDataContext is a linq to sql data context. Piece.Name is an an accessor property that does not do any computation. Basically, PopulateAllPieces returns a set of records from the database. Each of these records is a 'Piece' object. Piece.Name exposes the column called 'Name' in the database.

Comment: @JaceRhea I disagree, This example looks ok - ToList is called before the parallel part starts.

Comment: @JaceRhea No it's not.  The context, or a given query, is never accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: @JensKloster It'd be okay even if that wasn't the case, and it'd perform better too.

Comment: Are you sure you need that concurrent dictionary? Because you're loading it in to memory already using `ToList()`. Perhaps you could just use a dictionary and directly call `ToDictionary()`, albeit the question remains :)

Comment: @Silvermind He might need a `ConcurrentDictionary` because of how it's used after he populates it here, but if not, that may be a preferable option.

Comment: This is not using entity framework. PopulateAllPieces uses Linq to SQL behind the covers. Either way, that is all done and we have a List before the Parallel part starts.

Comment: @Servy I agree and the question is ok, but I was just wondering.

Comment: EF is not thread safe.
see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827599/parallel-doesnt-work-with-entity-framework .

Comment: @Thimape 1) He's not using EF 2) That would be irrelevant, he's not performing any operations that require the underlying query or the objects with in it to handle thread synchronization.

Comment: Can you check in the debugger to see how many items get added when it hangs?  How many do you have total; is it possible that it just takes a really long time, longer than you expected?

Comment: What is the point of adding all those items to a single data structure from multiple threads? The `ConcurrentDictionary` will have some locks going most of the time, so you're just adding a lot of overhead.

Comment: What is the call stack when your code hangs?

Comment: Try moving `Parallel.Foreach` outside the using statement. If it doesn't use the data context, nothing should change; if it does, you'll get a helpful error message.