# Entity framework Core ObjectDisposeException: "Safe handle has been closed"

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, objectdisposedexception

### Setup

Entity framework core 1.1

WPF application .NET 4.5.2

### The Problem:

I am sometimes encountering this exception while running a query on a sqlite database.

> System.ObjectDisposedException occurred   HResult=0x80131622
>   Message=Safe handle has been closed   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean&
>   success)    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle,
>   Boolean& success)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.sqlite3_db_filename(Sqlite3Handle
>   db, IntPtr zDbName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.db_filename(Sqlite3Handle
>   db, IntPtr zDbName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.sqlite3_db_filename(Sqlite3Handle
>   db, String zDbName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.VersionedMethods.Strategy3_7_10.GetFilename(Sqlite3Handle
>   db, String zDbName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.VersionedMethods.GetFilename(Sqlite3Handle
>   db, String zDbName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.get_DataSource()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Close()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Close()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.Dispose()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   FxConnection.Persistence.Repositories.PointNameRepository.GetConnectedDeviceNoTracking(PointName
>   pointName) in C:\Users*\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\project\project\Persistence\Repositories\PointNameRepository.cs:line
>   357    at
>   FxConnection.ViewModels.ProjectDeviceDatabaseViewModel.InitialLoading_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users*\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\project\project\ViewModels\ProjectDeviceDatabaseViewModel.cs:line
>   1729    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

The query which I am running inside a loop with a new context created just before the loop.

```
DatabaseContext.Devices.Load();
var deviceFrom =
    DatabaseContext.SocketSockets.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.SocketFrom)
        .Where(ss => ss.SocketTo.PointNameId == pointName.PointNameId)
        .Select(s => s.SocketFrom)
        .Where(s => s.IsConnected || s.IsSupplyOrGround == false)
        .Select(s => s.Device)
        .ToList();

var deviceTo =
    DatabaseContext.SocketSockets.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.SocketTo)
        .Where(ss => ss.SocketFrom.PointNameId == pointName.PointNameId)
        .Select(s => s.SocketTo)
        .Where(s => s.IsConnected || s.IsSupplyOrGround == false)
        .Select(s => s.Device)
        .ToList();
```

I am wondering if I am doing the query in the right way? Because sometimes it is entirely possible that there are no results. Might this be a problem?

Additionally, my `SocketSocket` table is basically a many-to-many mapping which contains `Socket` pairs.

The problem does not happen all the time at the same spot, even with the same data.

- Could this exception be caused by trying to have multiple context accessing the same sqlite database at the same time?

Comment: Looks like there are multiple BackgroundWorkers running.

Comment: To elaborate on @GertArnold's comment, It's not that you have multiple contexts - multiple contexts for concurrent queries should work fine - but Entity Framework does not support parallel or concurrent queries using the same `DbContext` instance. See answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43497310/2319351), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24702369/2319351) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827806/2319351) among others.