# Stopwatch with an async action which awaits calls from a database

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, stopwatch

How can I properly use the `Stopwatch` class with an async action event that awaits calls to my database asynchronously inside an async Post method on DotNet Core ?

### Why

To time my code and check for bottleneck. This is a simplified test method that will contain more code as time goes on.

### Errors

I tried using an Action event, a `Task` event and a `Func<Task>` event without success and they all give me errors which always occurs when I am awaiting a call from my database asynchronously using EF Core

When I use Action event

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll. Cannot access a disposed context instance.

When I use `Func<Task>`

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

***It doesn't print anything*** when I use `Task` event and the rest of the code executes without errors

### Code

Post Method

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostTest() {
    // my Database Context
    using DatabaseContext dc = _dbContext;
    
    // list of json data that will be returned back to the client
    List<object>? listJsonData = null;

    // stopwatch initialization
    Stopwatch sw = new();
    sw.LogActionAsync(nameof(OnPostTest), (async () => { // new Task(async () => { // new Func<Task>(async() => {

        // get list of data from TableTest database with a valid name and are not marked as delete
        List<TableTest> listValidTabletest = await dc.ListTest.AsNoTracking().Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces(t.strName) && !t.blnDelete).ToListAsync(); //<-- returns a list asynchronously and where the error occurs
        
        // initialize list that will be returned
        listJsonData = new();

        foreach (TableTest t in listValidTableTest) {
            // object that will be in the list of returned json objects
            var returnData = new {
                t.strName,
                t.arrPrices,
                t.strStartDate,
                t.strEndDate
            };

            listJsonData.Add(returnData);
        }
    }));

    return new JsonResult(new { 
        // return list or an empty array if list has not been initialized
        arrJsonData = listJsonData?.toArray() ?? Array.Empty<object>(),
        blnGetStatus = bool.TrueString 
    });
}
```

Stopwatch Extension Class

```
public static async void LogActionAsync(this Stopwatch sw, string? strMethodName, Action asyncAction, int intNbOfIterations = 1) {
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    List<Task> listOfTasks = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < intNbOfIterations; i++) {
        listOfTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(asyncAction)); // for Action event
       
        //listOfTask.Add(asyncTask); // for Task event
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
    //await asyncFuncTask; // for Func\<Task> event

    sw.Stop();

    // log duration to a file using Serilog
    Log.Debug($"{strMethodName} Action Duration: '{sw.Elapsed.Duration()}'");
}
```

---

EDIT:
I changed my `stopwatch` extension method to `async Task LogActionAsync...` and my `stopwatch` object to `await sw.LogActionAsync...` but now ***nothing is being logged****. Any idea ?

Comment: *Never* use `async void`. Asynchronous methods that return no data are `async Task`

Comment: Also this is C#, not C. You don't need to pass the caller method name, C# can pass it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of bugs in this code. To summarize:

1. `async void` in two places.
2. Missing `await`s.
3. Using a single database context concurrently.
4. Adding to a list of results concurrently.

So, let's fix these one by one.

---

1. `async void` in two places.
2. Missing `await`s.

As another answer noted, `LogActionAsync` should not be `async void` but should be `async Task` and `await`ed.

> I changed my stopwatch extension method to async Task LogActionAsync... and my stopwatch object to await sw.LogActionAsync...

You're still missing one more `async void`. It's a tricky one: lambdas, when assigned to `Action` variables, become `async void`. The proper delegate type for an asynchronous method without a return value is `Func<Task>`, not `Action`.

Code:

```
public static async Task LogActionAsync(this Stopwatch sw, string? strMethodName, Func<Task> asyncAction, int intNbOfIterations = 1) {
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    List<Task> listOfTasks = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < intNbOfIterations; i++) {
        listOfTasks.Add(asyncAction());
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);

    sw.Stop();

    // log duration to a file using Serilog
    Log.Debug($"{strMethodName} Action Duration: '{sw.Elapsed.Duration()}'");
}
```

And now you can properly use `await` everywhere.

---

3. Using a single database context concurrently.
4. Adding to a list of results concurrently.

As another answer noted, you will need one database context per action lambda. This is a limitation of Entity Framework (in turn imposed by a limitation of most SQL on-the-wire protocols).

The `List<T>.Add` method is also not threadsafe, and the code is potentially invoking it from multiple threads concurrently. It's possible to use a concurrent collection, but it's easier and cleaner to *return* result data instead of modifying a shared collection as a side effect.

But, really, I suspect that the concurrency in the posted code is an accident. It seems very odd to run N "iterations" of something *concurrently* when doing timing; I believe the desired semantics are to run N iterations of something *serially*.

If my assumption is correct, then the code should look like this:

```
public static async Task LogActionAsync(this Stopwatch sw, string? strMethodName, Func<Task> asyncAction, int intNbOfIterations = 1) {
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < intNbOfIterations; i++) {
        await asyncAction();
    }

    sw.Stop();

    // log duration to a file using Serilog
    Log.Debug($"{strMethodName} Action Duration: '{sw.Elapsed.Duration()}'");
}

public static async Task<T> LogActionAsync<T>(this Stopwatch sw, string? strMethodName, Func<Task<T>> asyncFunc, int intNbOfIterations = 1) {
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    T result = default;
    for (int i = 0; i < intNbOfIterations; i++) {
        result = await asyncFunc();
    }

    sw.Stop();

    // log duration to a file using Serilog
    Log.Debug($"{strMethodName} Action Duration: '{sw.Elapsed.Duration()}'");
    return result;
}

public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostTest() {
    // my Database Context
    using DatabaseContext dc = _dbContext;

    // list of json data that will be returned back to the client
    List<object>? listJsonData = null;

    // stopwatch initialization
    Stopwatch sw = new();
    listJsonData = await sw.LogActionAsync(nameof(OnPostTest), (async () => {
        // get list of data from TableTest database with a valid name and are not marked as delete
        List<TableTest> listValidTabletest = await dc.ListTest.AsNoTracking().Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces(t.strName) && !t.blnDelete).ToListAsync();
        
        // initialize list that will be returned
        var jsonData = new List<object>();

        foreach (TableTest t in listValidTableTest) {
            // object that will be in the list of returned json objects
            var returnData = new {
                t.strName,
                t.arrPrices,
                t.strStartDate,
                t.strEndDate
            };

            jsonData.Add(returnData);
        }

        return jsonData;
    }));

    return new JsonResult(new { 
        // return list or an empty array if list has not been initialized
        arrJsonData = listJsonData?.toArray() ?? Array.Empty<object>(),
        blnGetStatus = bool.TrueString 
    });
}
```

Comment: Very clear and on point. Even though the other answers helped me, this was very detailed. Thanks +1

Comment: Just make sure futur viewers to declare the variable result as nullable as per Visual Studio warning CS8600 and CS8603. Should be 'T? result = default' and 'public static async Task<T?> LogActionAsync...'

Answer (score 3):

You're not awaiting your call to `LogActionAsync`, so your call happens after your page action is over, which is why you get all those disposed exceptions. Your entire page and all its DI objects and database contexts and everything have long been disposed by that point.

`async void` should be considered a debugging tool, it helps find any async issue inexperienced people make right away!

Comment: I changed my method stopwatch extension method to 'async Task LogActionAsync...' and my stopwatch object to 'await sw.LogActionAsync...' but now nothing is being logged. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code has nothing to do with `StopWatch` and everything to do with entity framework.

Entity Framework `DbContext` is not concurrent safe.

You need to move the creation and disposal of the `DbContext` inside the `Task`.

Additionally, you should not be using `Task.Factory.StartNew` due to weird exception handling. And in this case, you should not use `Task.Run` nor `Task.Factory.StartNew` because you do not need a thread for concurrency.

Comment: "Entity Framework DbContext is not concurrent safe" -- yeah it is, that's what the async functions are for.

Comment: @Blindy async is not the same as concurrency. Read the documentation. EF DbContext cannot be used by multiple tasks, even if they are on the same thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43497310/1808494