# .Net Core Async Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to save all the KPI values that have been passed from View, but I ran into a problem, where I used foreach loop and this operation took way too long to process, so I loooked for solution and found Parallel.ForEach, but it throws me this error:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed.

Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Date,Name,Value,ID,CriteriaID,Employee")] List<KPI> KPI, List<string> employeeGIDs)
    {
        if (KPI.Count == 0)
            return Create();

        int managerID = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID").Value;

        var criterias = _context.Criterias.AsEnumerable().Where(x => KPI.Any(k => k.CriteriaID == x.ID));
        var users = _context.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(x => employeeGIDs.Contains(x.GID));
        var managerKPIs = _context.KPIs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ManagersId == managerID);

        List<KPI> kpisToAdd = new List<KPI>(KPI);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ParallelLoopResult parallelLoopResult = Parallel.ForEach(kpisToAdd, kpi => 
            {
                kpi.ManagersId = managerID;
                kpi.Criteria = criterias.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == kpi.CriteriaID);
                var user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => employeeGIDs.Contains(x.GID));

                if (kpi.Criteria.IsIndividual)
                {
                    kpi.EmployeeUserCode = user.UserCode;
                    kpi.EmployeeFullName = user.FullName;
                }
            });

            if (parallelLoopResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                var criteriasToAdd = kpisToAdd
                .Where(x => !managerKPIs
                .Any(m =>
                m.Date.Month.Equals(x.Date.Date.Month) &&
                m.EmployeeUserCode.Equals(x.EmployeeUserCode) &&
                m.Criteria.Name.Equals(x.Criteria.Name)));

                _context.AddRange(criteriasToAdd);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        return Create();
    }
```

I tried wrapping it into Task, but it doesn't work. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you want more than one connection to database use a connection pool : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?force_isolation=true&tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant

Comment: If you're using EF you can't. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827599/parallel-doesnt-work-with-entity-framework

Comment: Due to `AsEnumerable()` doesn't iterate your DbSet, you are using your DbContext concurrently - weird error mentioned is a side effect.. EF doesn't support its DbContext instances to work concurrently. Btw, why to create new list, if you got one through model binding?

Answer (score 1):

> This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed.

Yes. You can't use a single `DbContext` from within `Parallel` code.

> I used foreach loop and this operation took way too long to process, so I loooked for solution and found Parallel.ForEach

Well, that's *one* solution, I guess. You would need one DbContext per parallel thread, though. So instead of using one database connection to do N operations, you could use M database connections to do N operations.

That's not a great solution, though, because all those updates are still hitting the same database - probably the same table and closely related rows.

A better solution would be to do some bulk loading into your database. Then you have one database connection and one (or just a handful) of operations to load all the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Lets strip your example down to this;

```cs
_context.Criterias
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => something(x))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => somethingElse(x));
```

`_context.Criterias` is an `IQueryable` (and a `DbSet` but that's not relevant).

When you start enumerating an `IQueryable`, Entity Framework will start executing a database query and materialising the result set into dotnet objects.

When you call `.AsEnumerable()` you are preventing Entity Framework from building a more efficient query. In your case, you are forcing Entity Framework  to query the entire table, loading *every* record into memory for client side evaluation, *every* time you enumerate the results.

But it's only when you are calling `.FirstOrDefault`, that this enumeration will actually occur. That's when the query will be executed.

And you are calling `.FirstOrDefault` in a loop. Each iteration loading the entire table. No wonder you are seeing performance issues.