# How to insert data into a field using C # parallel programming

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using the Entity Framework and Linq technology but when I tried to use parallel.For it happens I have an Exception

This is my attempt

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextClass db = new DbContextClass();

                Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
                {
                    Category ct = new Category
                    {
                        NameCategory = "SomeText"                           
                    };
                    db.Categories.Add(ct);
                });                           

             db.SaveChanges();
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"i have an Exception"_ - which one exactly?

Comment: Please add more info and the exact exception that you have.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099359/entity-framework-and-multi-threading

Comment: this Exception => 'System.InvalidOperationException' and When I use the loop without parallel this does not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ths [github issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5962)

> Work on the assumption that none of the code is thread safe. All of the main APIs, like DbContext, DbSet, etc. are not thread safe. There are some thread safe parts, which are usually singleton or similar shared services, but almost all of that is internal.

This does not mean that you can't work in paraller with the same `DBContext`. Just change your code to the following (creating a new DBContext each time):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
       {
          using(DbContextClass db = new DbContextClass()) {
               Category ct = new Category
               {
                    NameCategory = "SomeText"                           
               };
               db.Categories.Add(ct);
               db.SaveChanges();
          }
      });                           

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```